# Full calendar: format title as link

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, encoding, fullcalendar

I use FullCalendar.js library (https://fullcalendar.io/) to display calendar. I want to add link for its title,

```
header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title'
},
titleFormat: '[<a href="url">]MMMM YYYY[</a>]', // <- HERE
```

but on displayed page I see (without [] I get strage I time. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I think you are better off manually creating the anchor tag and replacing the title with jQuery. `$('.fc-center').html('<a href="url">October 2017</a>');`

Comment: @davidchoo12: put you comment as answer, I'll mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.fc-center').html('<a href="url">October 2017</a>');`